# Visual Studio is opening web page in notepad

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I was working on webpage (Chat.aspx) accidently my system got shutdown. Now my visual studio opening webpage in notepad which is empty(showing nothing).

I also tried it to open with in Html editor, it also showing that file cannot be opened in selected editor please choose another editor.

How can i recover my work/code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once I faced the same issue , I researched a lot on internet but in the end I ended up with writing the page again. Basically File pointer in Memory becomes invalid  or corrupted due to which OS can not open the file in VS. [here is a link for you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/f28f37fb-511a-402f-a603-b012d117863e)

When I faced this problem one of the expert suggested me that it is not possible to get back your page .

If you have backup of your page then use that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue working in VS 2010 and I was breaking my brain. Luckily I had source control, so to solve the issue I manually deleted it the file and got latest version.